# How to show a table basing on the value of DropDownList in ASP MVC and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am developing an ASP .Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005.

I am using also Entity Framework and Code First Method.

I have a view 'Application' which contain a DropDownList.

The DropDownList load its items from the table Genre in the base.

I would like to show a table of values and that using a list already defined in the model.

The values of table depends on the value of DropDownList.
I have always this error :

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.

This is the code of my view :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MvcApplication2.Models.FlowViewModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Application
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<h2>Application</h2>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

<h2><%= Html.Encode(ViewData["Message"]) %> </h2>
   <div>         
         <%:Html.Label("Type :")%><%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedGenre, Model.GenreItems)%>

   </div>

   <table border = "transparent">
    <tr>
        <th>

        </th>

        </tr>

        <% foreach (var item in Model.FaItems) { %>
    <tr>
         <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nom_Famille) %> 
        </td>


    </tr>
    <% } %>
    </table>
</form>
</asp:Content>
```

and this is the Controller :

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Application(Genre genre)
        {
        var vv = new FlowViewModel();

        vv.GenreItems = new SelectList(db.Genres.ToList(), "ID_G", "ID_G");


        if (vv.SelectedGenre == "Famille")
        {

            vv.FaItems = db.Familles.ToList();


        }
        else if (vv.SelectedGenre == "Sous Famille")
        {
            vv.SFItems = db.Sous_Familles.ToList();

        }
        return View(vv);

    }
```

and finally this is the model 'FlowViewModel' :

```
public class FlowViewModel
    {

        [Key]
        public string IDv { get; set; }

        public List<Famille> FaItems { get; set; }
        public List<Sous_Famille> SFItems { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public SelectList GenreItems { get; set; }
        public string SelectedGenre { get; set; } 
}
```

**Stack Trace :**

[image]

Comment: Can you give us the stack trace of this exception?

Comment: That doesn't help that much, I wish to know the exact line that throws the exception, even if the stack trace picture would contain it I stil won't know where to fit it in your pasted code.

Comment: ah ok,,,the exception is in this line : 
<% foreach (var item in Model.FaItems) { %>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this condition is false:

```
vv.SelectedGenre == "Famille"
```

You don't set a value to `vv.FaItems` and therefor as long as `vv.SelectedGenre != "Famille"`, then `vv.FaItems` is null and will throw a `NullReferenceException` when trying to use foreach over it.

You can either add an else and put a new empty list, or wrap the foreach with an `if (vv.FaItems != null)` to avoid the exception.

Comment: thx but i don't think it s related in that test,,because when i remove it,,the exception still persist

Comment: When you remove what? The foreach? the *vv.SFItems* has the same problem but you don't use it. What thrown the exception if your foreach if wrapped with the *if (vv.FaItems != null)* I suggested?

Comment: I mean I remove all this part of code :
if (vv.SelectedGenre == "Famille")
            {

                vv.FaItems = db.Familles.ToList();


            }
            else if (vv.SelectedGenre == "Sous Famille")
            {
                vv.SFItems = db.Sous_Familles.ToList();

            }

Comment: Then you've removed the single possibility not to get this exception. You never put a value in **vv.FaItems** then it is now always **null**. Wrap your foreach with an *if (vv.FaItems != null)*

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative that will remove the need for duck-type checking.

```
public class FlowViewModel
{

    [Key]
    public string IDv { get; set; }

    public List<Famille> FaItems { get; set; }
    public List<Sous_Famille> SFItems { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public SelectList GenreItems { get; set; }
    public string SelectedGenre { get; set; } 

    public FlowViewModel()
    {
        FaItems = new List<Famille>();
        SFItems = new List<Sous_Famille>();
    }
}
```

Comment: thx joe ,,,your solution is also working,,,sorry can't set it 2 answers because Adam is the first one who answer ,,,but your solution is also works.
However, it s still a problem : no item shown in the table !!